# Error al intentar hacer un insert into en MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, script

Estoy realizando un procedure en el cual creo una tabla temporal y la lleno con el resultado de una consulta, o al menos es lo que intento hacer.

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table tblTemporal(
id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 idC bigint,
 idVersion bigint) ENGINE = MEMORY;

INSERT into tblTemporal
SELECT null,
       C.IdC,
       CV.IdCVersion
FROM Cuentas as C join CuentasVersion as CV on C.IdCuenta = CV.IdCuenta
WHERE C.EstatusC=2
      and CV.EstatusV=2
      and CV.IdCVersion=(select MAX(IdCVersion) from ContratoVersion where IdContrato=C.IdContrato)
      and CV.TipoPGenerar=2
      and CV.TipoPExihibicion=1
      and ((select DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) from Requisicion where IdContrato=C.IdContrato)<= DATE_ADD(CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo,INTERVAL NOW() DAY)
        or (select DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) from Requisicion where IdContrato=C.IdContrato) is null);
```

Al ejecutar el script anterior me marca el siguiente error:

> 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '3'

Lo que me parece extraño es que si ejecuto únicamente el select no me marca ningún error y trae los datos correctamente, espero alguien pueda ayudarme a saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Es posible que la tabla temporal se cree con las 2 columnas de **created_at** y **updated_at** (de tipo datatime) por defecto y que al pasar datos a esa tabla temporal esos campos contengan un valor nullo. Intenta verificar si es ese el problema.

Comment: Intente lo que comentaste y les asigne por default NOW(), tambien modifique el select para no tener error en le numero de campos, pero el resultado es el mismo: 
> 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '3'

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que te retorna la consulta?. Por lo que parece que dice el error es que se está intentando dar el valor '3' en una columna que espera un datatime... A ver si con el resultado del **select** podemos determinar donde y porque se produce el error.

Comment: Ya lo resolví,estaba interpretando mal el campo CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo, y al consultar intentaba agregar el valor del campo mencionado a la fecha actual. Con el ultimo de tus comentarios me di cuenta que CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo tenia el valor de 3 y de ahí se derivaba el error al tratar de agregar días al numero 3 :(
Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, me fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se generaba al estar interpretando mal el campo CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo, y al consultar intentaba agregar el valor del campo mencionado a la fecha actual.

Me di cuenta que CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo tenia el valor de 3 y de ahí se derivaba el error al tratar de agregar días al numero 3. Por lo que actualice el script y quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemporal (IdC, IdCVersion)
SELECT C.IdC,
       CV.IdCVersion
FROM Cuentas AS C JOIN CuentasVersion AS CV ON C.IdCuenta = CV.IdCuenta
WHERE C.EstatusC=2
      AND CV.EstatusV=2
      AND CV.IdCVersion=(SELECT MAX(IdCVersion) FROM ContratoVersion WHER IdContrato=C.IdContrato)
      AND CV.TipoPGenerar=2
      AND CV.TipoPExihibicion=1
      AND ((SELECT DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) FROM Requisicion WHERE IdContrato=C.IdContrato)<= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo DAY)
        OR (SELECT DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) FROM Requisicion WHERE IdContrato=C.IdContrato) is null);
```

Comment: En este caso, es recomendable marcar como resuelta la pregunta con su propia respuesta.

Comment: Es lo que intente hacer, pero no me deja hasta marcarla aún, tengo que esperar 2 días para hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Si el `select` funciona bien, puede que el problema sea intentar darle un valor null al campo con autoincrement, prueba a copiar los otros campos y que el autoincremento se auto rellene.

```
INSERT INTO tblTemporal (IdC, IdCVersion)
    SELECT C.IdC,
           CV.IdCVersion
    FROM Cuentas AS C JOIN CuentasVersion AS CV ON C.IdCuenta = CV.IdCuenta
    WHERE C.EstatusC=2
          AND CV.EstatusV=2
          AND CV.IdCVersion=(SELECT MAX(IdCVersion) FROM ContratoVersion WHER IdContrato=C.IdContrato)
          AND CV.TipoPGenerar=2
          AND CV.TipoPExihibicion=1
          AND ((SELECT DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) FROM Requisicion WHERE IdContrato=C.IdContrato)<= DATE_ADD(CV.GeneradaPorPeriodo,INTERVAL NOW() DAY)
            OR (SELECT DATE(Max(FechaCreo)) FROM Requisicion WHERE IdContrato=C.IdContrato) is null);
```

Comment: Si le quito el valor null me aparece manda el siguiente error:
>1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @CristianRamirez Has añadido los campos en el insert? Si no los específicas cuenta todos los de la tabla destino

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo que te tomaste en revisar el detalle, ya puede resolverlo.